# Correct Use of the Timer

Tags: c#, timer

pretty new here... 
I am making a program that will allow a user to control a sprite (walking on a surface/jumping/falling - the usual... pretty basic i know)

To make the sprite jump in such a way, so that the human eye can actually see a rise and fall on the form, i need to slow the process by which the program translated the sprite upwards.

I decided to use a timer, not SLEEP because i don't want the whole program to freeze.

Here's what i came up with:

```
private void jump()
{
    global.CharacterY = global.CharacterY - 1;
    framer_Tick(null, new EventArgs()); //pause program without freezing
}

private void framer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sprite.Location = new Point(global.CharacterX, global.CharacterY);
}
```

Called by this:

```
private void Stage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (global.counter >= 1 & e.KeyCode.ToString() == "D")
    {
        global.CharacterX = global.CharacterX + 1;
        jump();
    }

    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")
    {
        while (global.counter < 50)
        {
            jump();
            global.counter = global.counter + 1;
        }
        global.counter = 0;

    }
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "D")
    {
        global.CharacterX = global.CharacterX + 1;
        sprite.Location = 
            new Point(global.CharacterX, global.CharacterY);
    }
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")
    {
        global.CharacterX = global.CharacterX - 1;
        sprite.Location = 
            new Point(global.CharacterX, global.CharacterY);
    }
}
```

Now, the timer doesn't seem to have any effect. I assumed that placing the code to translate the sprite inside the timer would make it fire once every time the timer ticked. 
- Unfortunately i don't have the experience make the timer pause the program (preferably 30 times a second, at an interval of 33(ish)) -

Comment: soz, didn't realize.

Comment: Too bad you didn't start with wpf.  This would be trivial.

Comment: Is the process of making him go up and down smoothly not the same as making them go left and right smoothly?

Comment: Simply changing the location of the sprite will not do anything. You have to call `Invalidate()` on whatever control the sprite is being drawn on to see the effect. Also, you don't call `framer_tick` to get the process started. You  have to call start/stop on the timer object. When you call start, the tick handler will start getting called. When you call stop, it will stop. But I agree with @Chris. Your tick timer should be going off all the time because you should be redrawing the screen all the time. After that you just change the location of the sprite and everything will be fine.

Comment: Wrong approach.  The only reason that jump() appears to work is because the keyboard repeats the key when you hold it down.  Won't work for falling down again, the Timer isn't changing the global.CharacterY variable.  Use the timer instead to update your game objects.  And the KeyDown event only for setting their direction of motion.

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul Sasik That logic train makes much more sense than what i was attempting.

Comment: @Ben: Should I re-post my comment as an answer?

Comment: sure, it made sense to me and if i can help anyone else in my position, then why not?

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the location of the sprite will not do anything. You have to call `Invalidate()` on whatever control the sprite is being drawn on to see the effect.

Also, you don't call framer_tick to get the process started. You have to [call Start and Stop methods on the timer object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). When you call `Start`, the tick handler will start getting called. When you call `Stop`, it will stop.

To make all of your animation smooth and logic less problematic your tick timer should be going off all the time because you should be redrawing the screen all the time. With the screen refreshing itself you just change the location of the sprite and the animation will behave as you expect it.

Answer (score -1):

Simply changing the location of the sprite will not do anything. You have to call Invalidate() on whatever control the sprite is being drawn on to see the effect. Also, you don't call framer_tick to get the process started. You have to call start/stop on the timer object. When you call start, the tick handler will start getting called. When you call stop, it will stop. But I agree with @Chris. Your tick timer should be going off all the time because you should be redrawing the screen all the time. After that you just change the location of the sprite and everything will be fine. –  Paul Sasik

Comment: Please delete this. It's not what I meant. See my expanded answer below.